# How to join tables so every item in one of them shows up independent of the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
mysql> describe solution_sections;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| solution_section_id | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_order       | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| section_name        | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe suggested_solution_comments;

+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| problem_id            | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suggested_solution_id | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commenter_id          | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment               | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| solution_part         | int(3)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                  | date           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I am trying to do is to display the list of section_name from the solution_sections table. It only has about 10 rows in it.  And for every section name, to get the list of suggested_solution_comments associated with it.

The tables are linked by suggested_solution_comments.solution_part and solution_sections.solution_section_id

Here is what I am trying so far:

```
select section_name , comment , solution_part , display_order from solution_sections 
    left join suggested_solution_comments on 
    solution_sections.solution_section_id = suggested_solution_comments.solution_part   
    where suggested_solution_id = 188
    group by display_order;
```

But that returns nothing when there are no comments.  But even if there are no comments, I'd like to still display the list of section_names from the solution_sections table.

Thanks!!

Comment: If `solution_part` really _does_ reference `solution_section_id`, it should be named as such, use a foreign key, and have the same type _and size_ as the originating id.  Why is `comment` allowed to be `null` - isn't the point of this table to store comments?  What is that `date` referencing - the date of the solution, the comment, christmas, what?  If it is `insert_date`, consider making it a `timestamp`.  Oh, and... currently your query requires that comments be about `suggested_solution_id = 188` - try moving that to the `ON` clause (or eliminating it altogether).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

`where suggested_solution_id = 188`

Your query requires the suggested_solution_id have a value of 188, which will never be true for records that have no comments. Try adding in this:

`OR suggested_solution_id IS NULL`

Comment: unfortunately, adding that condition to the `WHERE` clause will still cause it be false for records that _do_ have comments, but are not part of the listed `suggested_solution_id`.

Comment: @X-Zero Presumably the author knows that, otherwise he wouldn't have included the WHERE clause in his example. I'm assuming the author wanted matching `suggested_solution_comments` if they existed, but he wanted to see `solution_sections` regardless.

Answer (score 1):

By using `suggested_solution_id` in the where clausule you are eliminating from the result any row that have <strike>no content</strike> no matching row in `suggested_solution_comments` table.

If you want to get results even when `suggested_solution_comments` has no content you can't use this field in the where clausule. <strike>or you have to consider the possibility that `suggested_solution_id`  could be NULL.</strike>

**EDITED** to take in consideration the comment by @X-Zero

Comment: No, he's not eliminating rows that have _no_ content, he's eliminating rows that do not have _matching_ content.  If he wants comments from all sections, he's probably going to have to eliminate the `WHERE` clause altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think your table structure is not the best to do this. if you have just a primary key in each table, and want to perform on join on those, it would need to refer to the same thing.. Otherwise, introducing a foreign key able to join on a primary key in the other table.

Comment: How would you structure the table to do this? You are right. I think the table structure is part of the problem, but I am not sure how to improve it.